# Bootstrap typeahead isn't properly connecting to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm attempting to connect my Bootstrap search bar, which uses typeahead, to a remote SQL database filled with different food items.  I know the typeahead is working, on some level, because when I type in 'C' the word 'Chicago' pops up, however, 'Chicago' is not in my SQL database.  I was following along with [this tutorial from YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0H6myhWkfA&list=PLFCC7BB1E12FEDC02&index=5).

Here is my HTML/PHP code for the web page:

Here is my search bar code:

```
<form class="navbar-search">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="search-query span3 pull-right" placeholder="Search" data-provide="typeahead">
    <div class="icon-search"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS code at the footer of my page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Bootstrap jQuery plugins compiled and minified -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS Code -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').typeahead({
            source: function(query, process) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'database.php'
                    type: 'POST';
                    data: 'query=' + query;
                    dataType: 'JSON';
                    async: true;
                    success: function(data) {
                        process(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my database.php code that is supposed to access the SQL database:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    // Connect to database
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    mysql_select_db('Menu_Items');

    // Retrieve the query
    $query = $_POST['query'];

    // Search the database for all similar items
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE name LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $array[] = row['name'];
    }

    // Return the json array
    echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

The database info is the following:

Database name: Menu_Items

Table name: Foods

The table consists of 2 columns, the 1st is a unique id, and the 2nd titled "name".

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with this and as far as I can tell I've followed the tutorial properly.  Any ideas on where I'm messing up?

Comment: well where is the error coming from? does the ajax call return the right data?

Comment: if you create a dummy form that posts data into the database.php are you seeing the correct information come back / is it running the right sql query.

Answer (score 2):

Holy Sql Injection batman!  Please use this form of composing your queries in the future:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends 
    WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code change this:

```
$array[] = row['name'];
```

to this:

```
$array[] = $row['name'];
```

And make sure you apply: mysql_real_escape_string to your: `$_POST['query'];` to be safe from SQL injection.