# code for ajax on text field using database

Tags: jquery, mysql, dreamweaver

I am making a web portal for an institute as an intern.

Currently making a module on the telephone directory. My mentor has asked me to apply AJAX on a text field for entering the employee name. I am using Dreamweaver CS4 and MySQL database through phpMyAdmin.

My problem is: How to apply AJAX on the text field such that the whole list of employee names appears as a list on entering single a character. It is the same as the Google does, it gives suggestions. I have searched a lot and got no code for this. Moreover Dreamweaver has very limited features and it's getting tough to work with it.

Comment: i also then need to fetch the corresponding phn number frm the database and paste it in the following text field which i have marked as read-only!

Answer (score 0):

I guess these two links might help u to achieve what you want. http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/jquery-php-mysql-ajax-autocomplete/. 
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: thanks Arun Sir.u given links for the autocomplete thing.i want it for displaying the list of suggestions ie: names starting with the entered alphabet. the names should be searched and looked from the mysql database. ur help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @user2613323 I think the answer provided by benedict might help you. Check that Link too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great solution that I've partially stolen from another question that will help you out if you use Twitter Bootstrap (Which is worth integrating if you haven't already, trust me, it will make your life much easier):

So here is the code for your text field for the name:

```
<form class="navbar-search">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="search-query span3 pull-right" placeholder="Search" data-provide="typeahead">
    <div class="icon-search"></div>
</form>
```

Next you're going to need some jQuery code to do the AJAX part:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Bootstrap jQuery plugins compiled and minified -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS Code -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').typeahead({
            source: function(query, process) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'database.php'
                    type: 'POST';
                    data: 'query=' + query;
                    dataType: 'JSON';
                    async: true;
                    success: function(data) {
                        process(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Finally you need to create database.php which will search your database and return the value back to your search bar:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    // Connect to database
    mysql_connect('[database url]','[username]','[password]');
    mysql_select_db('[database name]');

    // Retrieve the query
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']);

    // Search the database for all similar items
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $array[] = $row['name'];
    }

    // Return the json array
    echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

[Link to original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090287/bootstrap-typeahead-isnt-properly-connecting-to-sql-database)

Comment: m nt allowed to use twitter bootstrap or any other frontend. i want my problem solved only with given bounded specifications! thnx!